# PHP Deployer failing on line without errors

Tags: php, error-handling, chown, php-deployer

I have a PHP Deployer task to recursively change file owner of everything in the deploy path:

```
task('set_owner', function () { 
        run("chown -R someuser:www-data {{deploy_path}}");
    });

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock'); // Unlock after failed deploy
```

Deployer failed on this task since there are some `Operation not permitted` errors given by this commond. Fair enough, since those files don't need changing anyway. So I add `2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'` to prevent the errors from showing:

```
task('set_owner', function () {
        run("chown -R deployer:www-data {{deploy_path}} 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'");
    });

after('deploy:failed', 'deploy:unlock'); // Unlock after failed deploy
```

However when I run it Deployer still fails on this task:

```
➤ Executing task set_owner
[myapp.com] > chown -R someuser:www-data /var/www/myapp.com 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'
➤ Executing task deploy:failed
• done on [myapp.com]
✔ Ok [1ms]
➤ Executing task deploy:unlock
[myapp.com] > rm -f /var/www/myapp.com/.dep/deploy.lock
• done on [myapp.com]
✔ Ok [1s 364ms]
In Client.php line 103:
                                                                               
  [Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException (1)]                                    
  The command "chown -R someuser:www-data /var/www/myapp.com 2>&  
  1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'" failed.                               
                                                                               
  Exit Code: 1 (General error)
```

Is there a way to prevent Deployer from failing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some directives first to your deployment file :

```
set('writable_mode', 'chmod');
set('writable_chmod_mode', '0755');
```

Or make a chown with your webapp user.

Check your vhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/{your-webapp}.conf`.

Check your php-fpm config in `php{version}-fpm` directory to set the rights to your webapps user or a specific webapp user : `/etc/php/{version}/fpm/pool.d/{your-webapp-fpm}.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a `try catch` around the call so Deployer will just ignore and continue.

```
task('set_owner', function () {
        try {
            run("chown -R someuser:www-data {{deploy_path}} 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'");
        }
        catch(\Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException $e) {
            // For some reason a RuntimeException is triggered afeter executing the command even with 2>&1 | grep -v 'Operation not permitted'
        }
    });
```

Although I still don't get why Deployer throws this error even though the command line doesn't output anything.